# All Settings lost on restart of Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

Some strange thing is happening from last two days with my 
SublimeText 2. On restarting of my computer the settings 
are lost.

Below are my configuration details:
**SublimeText 2**: Portable Version 2.0.2, Build 2221.
**Operating System**: Windows XP Service Pack 3.
**Last Plugin Installed**: FavoriteFiles (https://github.com/facelessuser/FavoriteFiles)

Can anyone point the direction of problem.

Thanks

Comment: Can you access and view the file via Preferences > Settings-User? Try saving the (non-empty) file again and restart.

Comment: @IvanChau Ok will that